# Spring MVC - JSP ignores "${message}" and displays an empty page

Tags: apache, jsp, spring-mvc, tomcat, web.xml

I am new to Spring MVC framework and I was just trying to follow the steps in this example "https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_mvc_hello_world_example.htm". However, the page does not show whatever inside ${} and displays an empty page. I tried it with Tomcat v9.0 and Tomcat v6.0, both didn't work. I also tried both dynamic web module 2.4 and 3.1 but didn't work either. I would appreciate any help, I'm sorry if my mistake is simple or apparent.

Here's web.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id = "WebApp_ID" version = "2.4"
   xmlns = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

   <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
 
</web-app>
```

Here's HelloController.java:

```js
package com.tutorialspoint;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class HelloController {
   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)public String printHello(ModelMap model) {
      model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");
      return "hello";
   }
}
```

Here's HelloWeb-servlet.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package = "com.tutorialspoint" />

   <bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name = "prefix" value = "/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name = "suffix" value = ".jsp" />
   </bean>

</beans>
```

Here's hello.jsp:

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Hello World</title>
   </head>
   
   <body>
      <h2>${message}</h2>
   </body>
</html>
```

[Here's the result page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9ZXr.png)

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: can you post the hello.jsp too?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include it in the beginning. I've just added.

Comment: Why you are using .jsp in your URL? just read the last part of that tutorial

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked! Sorry for the silly mistake.